# PyCharm and f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, string-formatting, python-3.6

I am using the latest stable PyCharm 2016.1.4 and Python 3.6a1. Whenever I use the "f-strings" ([PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) PyCharm is complaining about `f` being an *unresolved reference*:

[image]

Is the literal string interpolation not supported by PyCharm yet? Or, should I have enabled or configured it separately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Literal String Interpolation is *now supported* in [PyCharm 2016.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/11/pycharm-2016-3-released/), the relevant feature request:

- [PY-18972 implement support for PEP 498 (f-strings)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18972)

Note that the stable [3.6 is scheduled to be released in December](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/).