# PyCharm f-string usage in a class displays warning (Unresolved attribute reference '__name' for class...)

Tags: python, pycharm

(short version of code)

```
class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __gender = "unknown"
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __hungry = False

    def __init__(self, name, gender, height, weight):
        self.__name, self.__gender, self.__height, self.__weight = name, gender, height, weight

    def toString(self):
        return f'{self.__name} is a {self.__gender}, {self.__height} m tall and weights {self.__weight} kg.'
```

PyCharm warns me: *Unresolved attribute reference '__name' for class 'Animal'*

The code is still working as intended. **Why does this warning pop up?**

f-strings seem a cleaner version of str.format for me and [they are also faster](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/).
PS. As I'm a newbie to Python, please feel free to bring out all the stylish errors or what could and should be done better :)

Python version: 3.6.4
PyCharm Community version: 2017.3.1

[Picture of the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3loZX.png)

Comment: Oh, and the funny thing is, PyCharm itself offers me a correction 'Convert to f-string literal' to the old code...

Comment: You've found a bug in PyCharm, I think. It is probably being thrown off by the use of double underscores in your attribute names, which invoke name mangling. If you're trying to access these from some other class, you'd need to use the mangled name. (Which is actually probably the wrong thing in this case: subclasses of `Animal` don't need their own name, gender, height, and weight attributes.)

Comment: Should I report it?

Comment: I'd report it. At worst, they'll do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215059/pycharm-and-f-strings) from about a year ago and also [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18972). It seems like it could be an issue with PyCharm.

However, if you remove the double underscores within the `f` string, the linter no longer complains.

Calling `''.format()` with the dunder prefixed attribute seems to not produce errors or warnings either.

As @kindall stated above [prefixing with the double underscore](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) invokes name mangling.

```
class Animal:
    __X = 'y'

    def __init__(self, name="", gender="", height=0, weight=0, hungry=False):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender 
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.hungry = hungry

    def to_string(self):
        return f'{self.name} is a {self.gender}, {self.height} m tall and weights {self.weight} kg.'

    def to_string_format(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.__X)
```

Also [they](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20774#u=1473837482325) seem to know about bugs pertaining to this issue. I would bring it up; it would be good for them to get some more information.